# Wireguard in a VM

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vpn, wireguard

I have a setup where on my Ubuntu host, I have a connection to a remote Wireguard server, and where on this host I have VMs where I would like to connect to other remote Wireguard servers.

Also I have no difficulties in connecting to the Wireguard servers from the VMs it gives me no internet connection in the VM.

I'm surprised because this setup used to work with Openvpn (TCP) on the host but not anymore. Did I miss something in the Ubuntu 22.04 bindings with Gnome boxes ?

I'm using Wireguard through wg-quick.